# Getting Data from App Inventor app in Eclipse app

Tags: java, android, app-inventor

Does anybody have any idea how to send data from an App Inventor app and the receive it in an app made in Eclipse.

I need to launch the app from within App inventor (already done this part) and send a string of data from app inventor to the other app and then manipulate the data in the other app.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Thanks
Patrick

Answer (score 1):

So I finally figured it out.

Here is my code from both apps:

App Inventor:
In the Activity Starter settings you need the following:

```
ActivityPackage: something.something.Packagename 
ActivityClass: something.something.Packagename.classname
ExtraKey: APP_INVENTOR_START
ExtraValue: Value that you would like to send.
```

This how you receive the value in Eclipse app:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String  ReceivedValue = extras.getString("APP_INVENTOR_START");
```

YES. IT IS REALLY AS SIMPLE AS THAT!

Comment: you can now find a detailed description of this solution [here](http://puravidaapps.com/savetosd.php)

Answer (score 1):

Patrick's answer is the preferred one, but if you really do want to do something like Einar mentioned (i.e. open a socket) you could have your Eclipse-based app run a small HTTP server and use App Inventor's Web component to communicate to it.

Answer (score 0):

If exchange of variables is impossible you might be able to do it opening à socket. If they both run on the same machine the latency would not be too high.

Comment: all I don't know is how to receive the data in the eclipse app. .getData() does not seem to work

Comment: If you can send data over a socket you should be able to receive it in the program you made in Eclipse. Are you running your app on the emulator or is it deploed to a debugging unit?

Comment: it is being deployed to a debugging device. and I unfortunately cant sent data over a socket because app inventor does not support that.